# Second largest in negative numbers

Tags: python

I am using this to find second largest in the array, it works fine in case of positive numbers but it fails in case of negative numbers.
Can you suggest this solution so it works for negative numbers also?

```
arr = [-3,3,-3,3];
k = max(arr)
m= arr[0];
i=0;
k = max(arr)
while i <(len(arr)-1):
    if(m<arr[i+1] and arr[i+1] !=k ):
        m= arr[i+1]
    i+=1
print m
```

Comment: Why not just sort the array and take either the 2nd or 2nd last entry?

Comment: @tadman You're suggesting an O(n*log(n)) solution to an O(n) problem.

Comment: I don't think negative numbers are the issue here.  If you shift them all upward to eliminates the negatives, I believe you will see an equivalent result.  For this sample data, it is printing -3, which is the second largest value (as opposed to the second largest list element).

Comment: @TomKarzes On trivial length arrays the run time is effectively the same. The simple *working* solution is often the best unless you have measurable performance concerns. Premature optimization kills code bases by strangling them with unnnecessary complexity.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is how it should handle the case where there is more than one instance of the largest value.  What result would you want for `[2, 5, 3, 5]`?  The second largest value is 3.  The second largest element of the list is 5.

Comment: so, @art, what is "the second largest" in your example, [-3, 3, -3, 3]? Is it 3, or -3?

Comment: @tadman You're assuming that the size of the sample data is indicative of the typical problem size.  On what do you base that assumption?

Comment: -3 is second largest @realharry

Comment: @TomKarzes If the question said "I need a performant solution" then I'd be concerned about the *O(n)* solution. Since it didn't, I'm not. Virtually every time this is a non-issue because Python is exceptionally good at sorting lists, even big ones.

Comment: @tadman Python uses a good O(n\*log(n)) sort implementation, but O(n\*log(n)) is O(n\*log(n)).  Whether it's twice as fast or twice as slow as another O(n\*log(n)) implementation is of secondary consequence.  Serious programmers will *always* balk when they see an O(n\*log(n)) solution to an O(n) problem.  It's automatic.

Comment: @TomKarzes If you're a game programmer who has to fear for every nanosecond because you're on a strict budget of 16.66ms then sure, these are valid concerns. If this was tagged C++ and Unreal I'd be with you. However, this is just a simple thing looking for a *working* solution in Python. An optimal solution is a whole other ordeal. Should we recommend using FFI and C++ to make this not only *O(n)* but to leverage SIMD as well? No. No we should not. "Serious programmers" know where they need to be careful about performance and where a simple solution is fine.

Comment: @tadman I assume this is a learning exercise for a class.  If so, then using an O(n) solution is probably required to obtain full credit.  I'm not saying using a sort isn't sometimes appropriate for a quick-and-dirty result, but it should not be suggested to someone without qualifying it with a warning indicating that it is only appropriate for small data sizes.

Comment: @TomKarzes Please don't make wild assumptions. Reblochon's answer is one I like because they answer it, and also explain options. Paul's answer is even better because it does it in one line using standard library tools.

Comment: @tadman Assuming it's a class exercise is hardly a wild assumption, and even if it's false, it doesn't change the goal of teaching good habits to a beginning programmer.  On the other hand, assuming the data size is always small, and that it will not be run many times, is a pretty reckless assumption.  As I said, suggesting the asymptotically slow solution is ok as long as it is qualified as such.

Comment: @TomKarzes Relax. I'm not [proposing a quadratic solution](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com) to a linear problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `O(n)` solution that finds and returns the second largest element in an array of numbers:

```
def second_largest(seq):
    largest = float("-inf")
    second_largest = float("-inf")

    for elt in seq:
        if elt > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = elt
        elif elt > second_largest:
            second_largest = elt
    return second_largest

arr = [-3,3,-3,3]
print(second_largest(arr))

arr = [-3, -4, -5, -1]
print(second_largest(arr))
```

#### Caveat:

Unless your sequence is very large (1000's of elements), it it probably faster to sort it and retrieve the second element.

Comment: Actually, the second to last element is not the same thing.  It would need to scan backwards for the second *distinct value*.  E.g. if the sorted list ends with `..., 8, 12, 12]` then the desired value is 8, not 12.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I saw your earlier comment. The OP did not specify, did he?

Comment: Eventually OP did (in the comments).  Your solution matches OP's clarified intent, but the full-sort solution needs to scan for the second distinct value.

Answer (score 1):

The bespoke tool for this kind of problem is the `heapq` module in the standard lib:

```
import heapq

scnd = heapq.nlargest(2, yourarray)[1]
```

This is O(n), much faster than sorting, though you'll only start feeling the difference north of a million entries or so.

Note: if you instead want the second largest *by value* one quick fix would be converting to a set if your elements are hashable:

```
scnd = heapq.nlargest(2, set(yourarray))[1]
```

If that's not an option:

```
frst = max(yourarray)
scnd = max(i for i in yourarray if i<first)
```